# Smart update on active record, choose fields to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve. I have a table targets, so the user creates a goal by setting the start date and end date of it automatically created days in my days table referring to that start and end date range. But when I edit the goal I have a problem because its start and end date values ​​are unique. I would like to edit the date values ​​if the user decided to change the start date to a more advanced date automatically the days that had already been created in the bank when he created the goal would be deleted if the user did not change the start date , but change the end date would be created in the bank only the dates forward of what had already been created before.

My code for Goal.rb and Day.rb is:

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :days, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :goal_salesmen, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :salesmen, through: :goal_salesmen

  validates_presence_of :date_start, :date_end, :name, :totalvalue
  validates_uniqueness_of :date_start, :date_end, scope: :company_id
  validate :end_date_is_after_start_date

  after_create :create_days


  def create_days
    rangeDate = (self.date_start..self.date_end).to_a
    rangeDate.each do |date|
      self.days << Day.create(date_day: date, goal_id: self.id )
    end
  end

private

  def end_date_is_after_start_date
    if date_end < date_start
      errors.add(:date_end, "Data of end cannot be less than the data of start!")
    end
  end

end
```

Day.rb:

```
class Day < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :goal
  has_many :day_salesmen, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :salesmen, through: :day_salesman
  validates_presence_of :date_day, :goal_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :date_start, scope: :company_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :day_salesmen

end
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear from your question what your overall goal is, but I'm going to infer:

- you want each company to have a set of `Goal`s whose days don't overlap
- you want each day to be associated with:

  - one `Goal` whose timespan contains it
  - 0 or more `salesmen`

One thing that jumps out is that you're tracking the start and end date for each goal twice: once in `goals.day_start`/`goals.day_end`, and again by creating a record in `days` for each day. You could then retrieve the start and end dates for a goal with something like this:

`Goal.where(id: YOUR_ID_HERE).joins(:days).group("days.id").select("goals.*, MIN(date_day) as date_start, MAX(date_day) AS date_end")`

Another problem is that `Day` records are created only when you first create a `Goal` record, and destroyed only when a `Goal` is destroyed. If you change the dates on a `Goal`, you'll need to calculate the difference to figure out which days need to be added and deleted. Ruby's `Set` class may be helpful here. You might even want to consider putting that logic into a regular method, rather than a callback, and having a controller invoke it.

One more thing to think about: it may not be strictly necessary to enforce uniqueness in the `Day` model (and ActiveRecord doesn't actually guarantee uniqueness). You could also detect multiple `Day` records with the same date and warn the user about the overlap, which may be preferable to throwing an error when the user tries to set an overlapping date.